# Dual-booting NixOS with another distro: How to share nix store and nix configuration?

Tags: ubuntu, nix, nixos

I have a working dual-boot setup with NixOS and Ubuntu on LVM with a shared `/home`. Everything was working fine until I tried to also install Nix on Ubuntu : the installer failed because of my `~/.nix-*` files created by NixOS. My reaction was to delete those files, and the installation was successful, but know when I boot on NixOS `nix-env` complains about my `~/.nix-*` files being incorrect...

So, is it possible to share the same `~/.nix-*` files between the two systems ? And is it possible to mount NixOS's `/nix` on my other system or is it a bad idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: It would probably be better to mount the stuff over from NixOS, because NixOS would have lots of required dependencies that plain Nix wouldn't even think about. (I've no idea how to do this, though.

Comment: Perhaps you can tell `nix` on one system to look for its files somewhere else (or with a different name?), maybe with a global config option? That would be stored in the `/etc` for one system, only.

Comment: BTW, you'll probably have to un-delete those files in order to install new packages on your NixOS system.

Comment: The problem is that I have no idea how to restore those files.

Comment: I will look into the global config solution.

Comment: If you deleted them via the GUI, then they're in your trash. If not, you'll have to restore from backup, if you have it. This has bitten me more than once. It's much better to rename files when you're unsure what the best move is.

Comment: It's probably best to run Nix system-wide on Ubuntu. Sander van der Burg has described how to set such a thing up, but it's probably a bit outdated. It is a good introduction into configuring nix-daemon though: https://sandervanderburg.blogspot.nl/2013/06/setting-up-multi-user-nix-installation.html

Comment: I'm not sure how feasible it is to streamline this, but you might be able to re-use some of NixOS' nix-daemon systemd service configuration on Ubuntu.